# what exactly does pinv do on singular matricies

Tags: python, numpy, regression, inverse

I have a general question about the numpy function [numpy.linalg.pinv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html).

I know that if my input matrix A is non-singular then, `numpy.linalg.pinv(A)` returns the inverse matrix of A.

However, if input matrix A is singular, then what exactly does `numpy.linalg.pinv(A)` return?

Comment: Try it out, see what happens. And always read the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html).

Comment: This is a math question more than a programming one. Here the wikipedia page of [Moore Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) giving you all the details.